# Why does Ruby FFI need attach_function calls when there are header files?

Tags: c, ruby, ffi

Is there a way to point Ruby FFI to a header file instead of writing attach_function calls?  A header file basically has the same exact information.

temp_convert.rb:

```
attach_function :temp_convert, [:float], :float
```

temp_convert.h:

```
float temp_convert(float temp);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because C header files are written in C but Ruby interpreters only interpret Ruby. Also, the header files might not even be available at runtime.

There *has* been talk about automatically generating `attach_function` calls from headers. However, as I hinted at above, this basically means that you must implement a full C compiler (well, the full front half of one, to be precise). At the moment, the Ruby implementers are more focused on making Ruby run as fast as C to alleviate the need to use FFI in the first place than writing their own C compiler (which is a non-trivial undertaking even though you only need to do the lexing, parsing, semantic analysis and typing parts, not the actual code generation or optimization).

Answer (score 2):

As Jörg says, implementing a header scanner means implementing quite a bit of the C compiler, to get everything right.

One thing you might like to try to ease the pain is the [FFI Swig Generator](https://github.com/ffi/ffi-swig-generator).  It uses swig to generate the FFI interface.  It still means you need to do a bit of work, which can boil down to a cut'n'paste job to generate the swig input file for simple interfaces.